# SQLite: Stop insertion on: expected n columns but found m

Tags: sqlite, csv, error-handling, insert

I'm using the `.import` command to insert a large csv into an SQLite db. Unfortunately, some of the lines contain the delimeter inside the value for the field. For example, each line is in the form:

```
id, title, first name, last name, location
```

but some lines have values like:

```
1, Mr, Bob, Saget, Sydney, Australia
```

and the comma in the location field causes an `expected 5 columns but found 6` error. Luckily, it's not important to me to insert every line, so I'd like to just not insert any lines that raise this error. Is this possible?

Parsing the csv with regex is a last resort as the file is very large and could take minutes every time I need to import it.

Comment: Fields containing the delimiter must be quoted correctly.

Comment: @CL. Okay, but the lines in question aren't quoted correctly, so what are my options for handling that input?

Comment: Quote them correctly, or remove them. (Do you have `sed`? Or an editor that supports regular expressions?)

Comment: I do have access to `sed`. However, that's a last resort, as the files are >1GB and I'd need to run the script multiple times a day. Does SQLite have a method for error handling this kind of stuff? It seems really strange to me that it would show me an error and then still insert the data into the table knowing full well it's bad data.

Comment: The `sqlite3` command-line shell is not designed to handle all exoctic cases; the `.import` command is intended to import `.export`ed data. If you have a different format, write your own importer, or convert your data.

Comment: Interesting. That makes more sense. I might take a look at the sqlite3 source code and see how easy it is to modify. Thanks for the insight.